# Is conversion necessary for integer comparisons in PHP?

Tags: php

Throughout much of the code I review, I often see things such as:

```
// $myvar could be anything

if (intval($myvar) > 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or similarly:

```
if ($myvar != null && intval($myvar) > 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

In an ongoing quest to produce more elegant and less-wasteful code, I am wondering if it is necessary to call intval(), for example, when performing a numeric comparison. My understanding from reading the documentation and from various responses here is that when a numeric comparison is asked for, it checks the type of the var and then performs either an integer cast or a string conversion depending on what it finds -- or are these the same as far as PHP is concerned, operations-wise?

Based on that, it seems the least expensive way is to tell PHP to cast it directly as an integer, as such:

```
if ((int)$myvar > 0) {
  // do stuff
}
```

However, I almost never see it written that way. Am I missing anything? Does PHP automatically do this any time it seems a comparison operator?

I realize in 99.9% of situations it is sufficient to just perform the comparison and let PHP type juggle on its own, but I see this so often that either I am missing something or many others are!

Comment: I always use `(int)$myvar` and never `intval($myvar)` for what it's worth. I also often `assert('is_int($myvar)')` when I know nothing else should ever be passed to a function without first being sanitized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given a reason to cast at all:

```
$myvar > 0
```

will have the same effect.  Either way, non-numeric strings can be coerced to 0 (this is one of PHP's many strange design choices), and numeric strings are coerced to the number they represent.  Thus after:

```
$myvar = "foo";
```

the following are identical (and false):

```
(int) $myvar > 0
$myvar > 0
```

Of course, casting to `int` may be useful in other situations.  Another useful function is [`is_numeric`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), which checks for a number or numeric string.

Comment: To add to this, `"2" > 1` is true, no need to say `(int)"2" > 1` or `intval("2") > 1`.

Comment: Your comment of "You haven't given a reason..." is really the core of what I was asking; I see code littered with intval() (and occasionally is_numeric()) and I believe it is mostly because people don't understand the need -- or lack of need -- for them. To your last example, I idly wonder if (int)$myvar > 0 and $myvar > 0 result in the same number of instructions being performed or not.

Comment: @futureal, `is_numeric` can certainly be useful, to avoid the silent coercing to 0 (and for instance throw an exception instead).  There are also places where `(int)` is needed.  One obvious example is truncating a number (or numeric string).  However, in cases like the question, `(int)` doesn't really buy you anything.  As far as performance, I don't know.  But I wouldn't worry about it.  After all, it's an interpreted language, and micro-optimization is a waste of time.

Answer (score 3):

If in doubt, do the most reliable and predictable thing.  In this case, that means doing the casting yourself.

```
if ((int) $myvar > 0) {

}
```

will give the most reliable results.  Furthermore it is very legible and obvious what you're doing.  I would definitely prefer to read explicit code than code that relied upon magic PHP behaviour.

---

As an example, take the instance where you are comparing two variables, rather than an integer and a variable.

```
if ($a > $b) {
```

This will do an integer comparison if either `$a` or `$b` is an integer. If they are both strings, the comparison will be a string-based one.  If you do the casting yourself, you know what comparison is being done every time.

Comment: It would be better to cast var to integer in a separate statement: `$myvar = (int) $myvar`, what if you want to use the value inside `if`?

Comment: @German Yes, you should do that if you then proceed to use `$myvar`.

Comment: I do agree -- when in doubt, adding the cast makes it very obvious what the developer's intent was. That is my inclination as well and I am happy to see that the majority here seem to agree.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to always know what types of data I'm dealing with, and only convert when necessary.

If you're writing a function that should take ints as arguments, you don't need to convert them. Just check the arguments' types with `is_int`, and use `assert` or `trigger_error` to show a runtime error if they aren't integers. That way you'll know right away if someone is misusing your functions.

On the other hand, if you're getting input from the user (like $_GET or $_POST), it will probably be a string. So before you use it for any calculations, you should convert it to an integer.

Comment: I do normally cast or run a check inside a function if the type is significant, so, agreed. Actually I have never seen assert() being used outside of unit tests or other debugging operations myself, although we do use trigger_error() to generate a message -- usually at the E_NOTICE level -- if something is being misused.

Answer (score 0):

Use (int) as a cheap and effective filtering mechanism. If it comes across the value:

```
$var = "mm";

echo (int)$var ;
```

will cause it to become 0 which will fail a test such as:

```
if( (int)$var === 0){

// it must be an integer greater than zero

}
```

If $var is not set, then yes you will throw a warning, hence you use is with isset()